# Xcode: Tableview checkmarks

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tableview, xcode4.3

I wanna know how to check some cells in a table view. Does somebody know how to do that?
I want, when the user presses a cell then a checkmark will appear and if the user presses again it ill disappear agian. The user should be available to check more than 1 cell at a time ;)

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for that: http://blog.walkingsmarts.com/creating-radio-button-and-checkbox-lists-using-uitableview/ sorry for the absence of screenshots and the project download .) But the code is there and it works.

Comment: ill just check it out :)

Comment: Im not good at nib files and old Xcode... Can you please just take all the code i need and paste it here on stack overflow? I'm sorry that i need so much help but I'm really new at Xcode :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `accessoryType` property of `UITableViewCell` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. You just need to keep a `BOOL` variable that will let you  allow to change between `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

EDIT 1 -

Code for doing so-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *tableCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isSelected = (tableCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark);

    if (isSelected) {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else {
        tableCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```